# win32 application c++ if-else not working

Tags: c++

http://pastebin.com/8YJ7LJYA

The code you can see if you klick on the link. if I enter 123 and 123 the msgbox wan´t appear. also with other passwords won´t work.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it _in the question itself_.

Comment: We don't want to see tons of irrelevant code. We want to see just the minimal code needed to reproduce the error. Also, you really need to ask a specific question that we can answer, including explaining the expected and actual results, troubleshooting you've already done, and so on.

Comment: but they say that is too much code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INPUT1` is defined to `100`, so `INPUT1 == 123` will never be true.

`INPUT2` is defined to `101`, so `INPUT2 == 123` will never be true.

Consider using `GetDlgItemText` to fetch the text in textbox and `lstrcmp` to compare texts.